# Rails ActionText attachments lost after docker rebuild and docker-compose up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, attachment, actiontext

I've setup ActiveStorage and ActionText by following the official guides. I can attach images and videos in local environment(localhost:3000). All the things are working well, even after I restart the server.
[image]

So I deploy my code change to staging. It looks all good when creating the blog. But I found if I redeploy the code(rebuild the docker image and start service by docker-compose up). The attachments for ActionText will just been invalid, which looks like this:
[image]

Comment: I am seeing this same behavior. I haven't found a solution yet.

Comment: please refer to my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the root case is: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/37405

It's a Rails bug, when we are using `rich_text_area_tag`, here will be the problem.

If you use `rich_text_area` instead this problem will not be there any more.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem that was caused by me not configuring `docker-compose` correctly. I had:

1. Selected `Disk` for the ActiveStorage "service". This is OK because I don't expect that my app will store tons of stuff using ActiveStorage–just ActionText blobs in a very limited way.
2. I didn't set up the volume for the ActiveStorage `Disk` service to be persistent across restarts. Every time I deployed or otherwise restarted the `docker-compose` services, the volume was recreated, erasing every ActionText blob.

Once I properly configured a persistent volume for ActiveStorage, the ActionText attachments started working across deploys/restarts.